# Order by, group by, first result in HQL (convert from Oracle SQL)

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql, sql-order-by

How would represent the following Oracle SQL in Hibernate HQL.

```
select table_num
, room_id
, min(event_type) keep(dense_rank first order by changed_on desc) 
from room_history 
group by table_num, room_id;
```

The idea behind the query is to order the table "room_history" by "changed_on" datetime column and then group it by "table_num" and "room_id" pairs whilest keeping the first "event_type" for each group. The mentioned query works for Oracle but I have trouble converting it into HQL.

Purpose is to get the latest "event_type" for "table_num" and "room_id" pair.

Comment: That seems to be the problem that I can't seem to find a suitable HQL syntax that would yield the same result. Why I need it as HQL is beacuse I indent to use it within a larger query and therefore cannot do it on my app side.

Comment: You could post the HQL you tried, so that we can point out the errors.

Comment: It seems there is no syntax in hql to achieve this. Found a way around (see answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is not achievable

I ended up converting the following SQL query instead. It is not perfect but it does the job for my purposes.

```
select table_num, event_type et from room_history where id in (select max(id) from privacy_history group by msisdn);
```

I was able to do this assumptions since when for this table always a.id > b.id then also a.changed_on> b.changed_on.